# Encoding video files in different formats

Tags: video, encoding

I am working on a site which would allow users to upload a video and my site would encode into 3 formats, wmv, iPod and zune. Are there any 3rd party tools/API's that can be used to do this? I am not sure how sites like http://channel9.msdn.com/ , http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ have got this.

Comment: What's your server setup? Windows or Linux? PHP, ASP, Rails? etc

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question. The environment is Windows. Not sure if Win Server 2003 or 2008 though. It would ASP.NET website. Just want to have a reliable solution without too much coding from my end. Of course, one has to take risks while using 3rd party stuff!

Answer (score 6):

Try [libavcodec/ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).

Edit: Since you're using .NET, you can try [FFmpeg.NET](http://ffmpegdotnet.codeplex.com/) or [FFLib.net](http://www.intuitive.sk/fflib/post/fflib-net-released.aspx), 
besides [Media Handler Pro](http://www.mediasoftpro.com/), which you already mentioned.  However, I haven't personally used any of these bindings.

Comment: I use ffmpeg on a social networking site I manage. It's proven invaluable. Configuration can be a little hairy, but nothing a bit of Googling didn't fix.

Comment: If you are going to use ffmpeg or libavcodec for your encoding backend, be sure you understand the legal ramifications of doing so.  FFMPEG reverse engineers video codecs (like H.264) that are protected in patent pools. This is against the law in some jurisdictions (like the United States).

Comment: Nick, it's hardly as simple as that. Under Sega v. Accolade (digital-law-online.info/cases/24PQ2D1561.htm/…), reverse-engineering (even including disassembly, if necessary) is legal, "when no alternative means of gaining an understanding of those ideas and functional concepts exists."

Answer (score 1):

You could use an external service such as [encoding.com](http://www.encoding.com/) although this will probably work out more expensive.

Expression encoder will also encode to those formats and it has a nice, easy to use SDK or command line interface if you prefer.

Comment: Ya I know, its really expensive. I did stumble across http://www.mediasoftpro.com/ which seems to be a good option but not sure about its performance yet.

Comment: It looks like mediasoftpro.com is just a .net wrapper around ffmpeg

Comment: Yup seems that way. Thanks a ton guys, I will be looking more into ffmpeg/mediapro for my site.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the more robust commercial offerings are:

[Adobe Flash Media Encoding Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaencoding/)

[Wowza Media Server Pro](http://www.wowzamedia.com/products.html)

[Rhozet Carbon Coder](http://www.rhozet.com/carbon_coder.html)

[MainConcept Reference](http://www.mainconcept.com/site/prosumer-products-4.html)

These solutions are expensive but extremely high quality.  You get what you pay for in my opinion.